# using a producer / consumer pattern with Quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net

Till today I used Quartz.net for a single job or different jobs that worked independently.. now I need to run 2 different jobs based on some data I've. I've created 3 jobs for now and called them one after the other (am doing ugly things I won't write here to run them one after the other...)

I was wondering if I use a queue, shared between the jobs, (or even 3 background worker that works on different queue) can I have this working with Quartz.net?

I mean I have the main job run, the other works on their on queue, but the main job is not scheduled until the worker is finished?

I've just put on the main job the `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute

Thanks